# Delete Substring From String Using Regexp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

```
string = '/location/start:2015-06-06/end:2015-06-06'
```

and I would substitute the `start` and `end` paramaters.
Therefore, I would like to delete everything like `start:2015-06-06` and `end:2015-06-06` by using `Regexp`.

But I do not know how.

Comment: Maybe you should start here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/regular-expressions-javascript and then show us what you come up with.

Comment: Don't you want to remove `/` before `start` and `end`?

Answer (score 2):

```
string = string.replace(/start:[\d-]*/g,"").replace(/end:[\d-]*/g,"");
```

Comment: Sorry, brain is running slow today. That should be:  string.replace(/(start|end):[\d-]*/g,'');

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var str = '/location/start:2015-06-06/end:2015-06-06'; 
var result = str.replace(/start:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/, 'something');
```